# Multi-select breaking on no selection and OK

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on a Cordova project and found this example on the jquerymobile site. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/

When I use this and select anything it works fine.

The problem arises when I deselect everything and press OK. 
(If I press cancel it works fine closes the dialog)
The application freezes completely with no error message and no indication of what went wrong. The application closes after a few seconds while being frozen for the duration.

Here is the exact code i am using

```
<select id="txtdescriptions" multiple="multiple"> 
        <option value="1">Rich</option>
        <option value="2">Poor</option>
        <option value="3">Tall</option> 
        <option value="4">Short</option>  
        <option value="5">Dark hair</option>  
        <option value="6">Light hair</option>  
 </select>
```

Here is styling code above the code

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Green2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
```

Here is my link to the javascript jquery mobile I added below everything

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

What can I do to fix this and what is causing this issue

Comment: ..and the code inside the OK button?

Comment: @deblocker there is no code on the ok button. that is my issue. I am assuming the code is in one of the libraries

Comment: There isn't any OK/Cancel button in the demos in Your link, please explain more about the OK/Cancel buttons, otherwise it is impossible to help You, just guessing.

Comment: I also do not understand why my example has an ok and cancel button. The code I have pasted here is exactly what i am using. Ill be happy with a solution without an OK button as long as it does not error. my confusion is the reason im asking the question so im sorry @deblocker but I have no idea